# Can we add pipe in [innerHTML] property binding dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm recently working for a fix where i need the `pipes` in angular to be added dynamically so I use `innerHTML` property binding - But the problem is that the only when looping the data I will know which kind of pipe should be added

**Pipes in InnerHTML**

```
<span [innerHTML]="element | pipe1 | pipe2"></span>
```

The above example is working as expected but in case if if try to bind the pipe dynamically like below it is not working

```
bindPipe = "| pipe1 | pipe2";

<span [innerHTML]="element + bindPipe"></span>
```

I have added the pipe types as a string property in my `component.ts` and I have mapped it in the HTML but originally the pipe types will be looped dynamically inside a array of values

In the above case the pipe type is consider as a string concatenation and renders in the UI - Is there any option of binding pipe type like above - I might be wrong but I tried all the solution like adding a directive and binding it but nothing works

I think, I'm missing something little - Please help

**Edit**

If I try like code below - no odds

```
bindPipe = "<span>test | pipe1 | pipe2</span>"

<span [innerHTML]="bindPipe"></span>
```

Comment: why do u think it should work ? as far as i can see you are passing string to [innerHTML] = ...  Innerhtml executes a code segment, not a string

Comment: Updated my question can you please check

Comment: This You can perform from your ts file. You can call pipe from ts file and bind value in HTML

Comment: That will act as a class right - why should i go to pipes then

Comment: You can call pipe transform method from your ts file , if want to do something dynamically - this is only the way.